# Publishing two IoT Edge modules to one IoT Edge device on Staging and Production environments via one Azure pipeline and one Release

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I need to publish two IoT Edge modules to one IoT Edge device on Staging and Production environments via one Azure pipeline and one Release.
I parametrized the Azure container registry's address, username, and password via variables (Build variables and JSON variables are used) and the solution works for one environment. But, how can I do the same for both environments via one Azure pipeline and one Release?

**deployment.template.json**

[image: deployment.template.json]

**module.json**

[image: module.json]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.